# Code for broadcasting wifi packets without a network

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, internet

Is it possible to send a packet over wifi without having joined any kind of network (ad-hoc or not)?

I would like to be able to send packets in the air without joining a network. Another device in monitor mode would be able to recognize which packets it should treat.

Any code for this ? Or can you guide me how can I write a socket programme over (maybe Python)that can broadcast such probe request with some message in it. So that the monitoring device can identify the packet and read the message.

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as they are on most SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se]. Also, questions about programming are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The code depends on the platform, programming language and many other things. However you need to have in mind some basic concepts.

This type of communication will be called IP BROADCAST communication. The destination MAC address of the packets should be FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF (Broadcast destination MAC address).

The destination IP address of the packets should depend on the specific network so this will be harder. I do not exactly know how will you make the receiving phones or wifi devices NOT to drop the packets when they will see an IP that does not belong to their network. Maybe 255.255.255.255 will work but I am not sure.

Also, you should use the UDP protocol and not the TCP protocol, so you will open an UDP socket instead of a standard TCP one.

In UDP the receiving device does not send anything back. It only receives.